# How to import a large mysql file using putty from local drive?

Tags: mysql, centos, putty

I need to upload a large mysql file using putty on Centos server. I am using below command lines for importing this file. Here is the code:

```
mysql -u socialto_newDb -p

use mydatabase; 

mysql>SET autocommit=0 ; source C:/Users/jmd/Downloads/database.sql ; COMMIT ;
```

I am getting the error number 2 and error message is 'Failed to open file' C:/Users/jmd/Downloads/database.sql. Please let me know what is the issue and help me for the same.

Comment: http://www.mysqldumper.net/

Answer (score 1):

Try this one hope it help you to solve your problem. Command for import large SQL file with command/terminal.

```
mysql -u username -p database_name -v < C:\xampp\htdocs\file.sql
```

**username**  =  your MySQL username
**database_name**  =  Your Database name
**C:\xampp\htdocs\file.sql**  =  Your File location

Comment: Hey, I am already selected a database where I need to import. So I need a command after use database command.

Comment: Like this: D:\>cd wamp
D:\wamp>cd bin
D:\wamp\bin>cd mysql
D:\wamp\bin\mysql>cd mysql5.5.8 (whatever ur verserion will be displayed here use keyboard Tab button)
D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.8>cd bin
D:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.8\bin>mysql -u root -p password db_name < "d:\backupfile.sql"

Comment: mysql -u username -p password -v < C:\Users\jmd\Downloads\database.sql

Comment: mysql -u username -p  -v < C:\Users\jmd\Downloads\database.sql

Comment: mysql -u username -p database_name  this is the right command. please follow the command perfectly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136138/discussion-between-deepak-bhardwaj-and-faisal).